# How to recover specific folder from a formatted partition?

Tags: linux, data-recovery, firefox

I use firefox-sync to manage all my logins information and firefox-sync's password is the unique password I save manually.

Currently I has problems with my O.S and I decided reinstall it. But also I have 2FA enable for mostly of my accounts, and firefox-sync is not the exception, and firefox-sync's 2FA is based on my gmail, so when I tried get logged on firefox-sync, Firefox asks me for my verification code, but my verification code is in my gmail, and my gmail's password is in firefox-sync.

So I lost access to all my accounts, I lose my gmail, github, gitlab, stackoverflow, discord, etc etc... :'(

From the gmail side, I tried all that gmail let me try but unsuccessfully.

So, the only possibility that I see, is recover the information of the formatted partition and rebuild the previous state of Firefox. I mean:

Reading about Firefox logins, and taking a look to Firefox's workdir (`$HOME/.mozilla`), I see Firefox saves login's info in a json file located in `$HOME/.mozilla/$profile$/logins.json`.

So, this is my idea. Recover the `.mozilla` workdir from the formatted partition, and then, replace it over the `.mozilla` workdir of the current environment to can get access to the last Firefox's state before formatting, and consequently can get access to my login's info.

But this raises me two fundamental questions:

1. I noticed the error almost immediately so I stopped using the disk to avoid any type of overwriting, from what I understand the information is still there, the problem is in the recovery that may not necessarily have structure. How feasible is it to recover the entire `.mozilla` workdir from the formatted partition? How can I do it? What tools and what approach should I use?

and

2. In case there is definitely no way to recover the entire directory, what should be my target files to recover? I mean: `$HOME/.mozilla/$profile$/logins.json` is the main target file, but this contains login's info encrypted. So what would be the files that next to this I would need to replace so that when I open Firefox I can see my login's info?

I really care about this any help however minimal, whether it be with reading resources, or with explanations of the file system, or with ideas, or whatever, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Start with this https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Comment: https://www.r-studio.com/free-linux-recovery/

Comment: do have any other devices that might be still logged into gmail?  like a old phone or old tablet?

Comment: no device not even the alternative emails they are all old to which I no longer have access, nothing!....

Comment: I tried first with `r-linux` and couldn't recover anything, then with `photorec`, and after a long process I managed to recover the `logins.json` file and the private keys with which firefox encrypts the passwords.

Now the problem is to find the algorithm that firefox uses to decrypt the passwords, a priori I already have the essential information I just need to know how to process it.